# Dipslay the Hex value in the form of byte

Tags: c#, byte

I have this integer (27493164)  and I'd like to put it into byte array in this form:

[image]

I got that value using this:

```
string result = ((uint)total).ToString("X");
```

But I do not know how to insert it into byte array with that form.

Comment: Are you saying you want an array of ASCII strings representing the bytes? Because actual byte values don't look like that inside the computer. `04 A3 83 2C` is an ASCII representation in hex of the numbers stored in the array. Or are you trying to represent `total` as an array of its byte values?

Comment: The image I included is a screenshot of a file composed of bytes, I am trying to replicate it, it was able to write those Hex into byte values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your wording, however

```
// int bytes
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);

//bytes to hex
var hexData = intBytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))

//hex to string
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",hexData));
```